# In excel, why can I create a relationship between Table 1 and Table 2, but I can't create one going in the opposite direction?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have two tables containing related data; both have a `Participant_ID` column. I've created a relationship between `Table_1` and `Table_2` with `Table_2` as the lookup table. This is so that by setting up a Pivot Table in a certain way I can see where a value in `Table_1`'s column is not in `Table_2` (it will come up as "blank" in Pivot Table). It works fine. I also want to know the opposite, i.e. if there are values in `Table_2` that aren't in `Table_1`. Thus, I've figured that I need to create the reciprocal relationship with `Table_2` as my starting table and `Table_1` as the lookup table. Whenever I try this, I get:

> this relationship cannot be created because one or more columns contains duplicate values

This isn't true - neither of the columns contain duplicates, or any blanks that would be picked up as duplicates. I've checked a million times.

No matter what I do or change, I get this error. I've even tried this on completely new tables with only 1 row of data in each and thus no duplicate values, and once again, the first relationship can be created but when I try to create one in the opposite direction I get the same error message.

Yes, I know I can use other formulas to check if a value is in one table but not another, but I wanted to use a Pivot Table to also easily look at other similar fields between the two tables as well.

It's driving me absolutely crazy. In sum, why can you create a relationship between `Table_1` and `Table_2`, but not between `Table_2` and `Table_1`?

Image 1: The relationship in one direction can be created.
[image]

Image 2: The error message I get when I try to create relationship in opposite direction
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid we can't help you without knowing more details: please post some sample data on which you can recreate the issue, also describe the exact steps necessary to recreate the issue.

Comment: Sorry - new to this. Added links to pictures

Comment: @Angela please accept my answer if it is correct or tell me why it isn't so I can improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a relationship loop, which is prohibited according to Microsoft's [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/relationships-between-tables-in-a-data-model-533dc2b6-9288-4363-9538-8ea6e469112b#__toc319397752):

> **Self-Joins and Loops**
>
> Self-joins are not permitted in a Data Model. A self-join is a
> recursive relationship between a table and itself. Self-joins are
> often used to define parent-child hierarchies. For example, you could
> join an Employees table to itself to produce a hierarchy that shows
> the management chain at a business.
>
> Excel does not allow loops to be created among relationships in
> a workbook. In other words, the following set of relationships is
> prohibited.
>
> Table 1, column a   to   Table 2, column f
>
> Table 2, column f   to   Table 3, column n
>
> Table 3, column n   to   Table 1, column a
>
> If you try to create a relationship that would result in a loop being
> created, an error is generated.

Comment: Please include a relevant quote. This link may not work in the future.

Comment: @Anaksunaman you're totally right, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Lol! Always nice to know I'm *totally* right. ;) But you're welcome. =)

Comment: Sad to hear this is the case, but thank you!